# CXF how to set the locale for the reason tag?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have a web service that is based on CXF.
when I use the CXF soap faults, by default the I got the following format for the reason tag:

```
     <soap:Reason>
        <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Le service n’est pas accessible.</soap:Text>
     </soap:Reason>
```

what I want is is how can I change the locale of the reason text 
to other language ? ex: fr
ie: how can I get the following result:

```
<soap:Reason>
        <soap:Text xml:lang="fr">Le service n’est pas accessible.</soap:Text>
     </soap:Reason>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved :)

After hours of debugging I found that the language used in  `<soap:Text xml:lang="en">`
is hardcoded in the interceptor `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor`
In fact, the value of the language is aqcuired by the method `getLangCode()` defined in the internal class `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptorInternal`
here is the code of the method used to get the language, as you can see it almost hardcode the language to en

```
  private String getLangCode() {        
            String code = LOG.getResourceBundle().getLocale().getDisplayLanguage();
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
                return "en";
            }
            return code;
            }
```

The version of CXF I am using is `2.2.6`, I am forced to use it because of legacy system that supports only java 5,
But I found that this issue was fixed starting the version `2.6.7`
In this version, a new attribute: `lang` has been added to the super class `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault` to specify the language.
In the code of the soap fault this is done by simply doing this:

```
fault.setMessage(reason);
fault.setLang("fr");
```

that's it :)